# Get play count of a track from Spotify API

Tags: spotify, spotify-app

Is it possible to get the play count of a song (for the current user)? I only found [Toplist](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-toplists-toplist.html) and the [Track](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-models-track.html) class, but neither tells me how often a user listened to a song.

Comment: @Thomas, there is already a tag for Spotify.  Why did you add a new one to over twenty questions?

Comment: @Charles his comment to the edit was "Introducing new tag for spotify apps, to distinguish from other spotify apis"

Comment: @Charles, seemed appropriate, considering the existence of the libspotify and cocoalibspotify2.0 tags

Comment: @Thomas, those tags are for specific libraries that implement the API.    Regardless, I now see what you're talking about -- there's a *new* Spotify API for "apps."  The tag wiki is confusing, and I'll be submitting a correction...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to retrieve that data at the moment.

Comment: If you care about this feature, please give it a "thumbs up" on GitHub: https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/70

Comment: It is no longer possible to upvote this on GitHub as the repo has been archived.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible through the Spotify API right now. 
The [Last.fm API](http://www.last.fm/api/show/track.getInfo) does offer information similar to this, as a potential work-around.

Answer (score 3):

Marked as not right now on the Spotify support site.

http://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-Ideas/Personal-play-count-for-songs/idi-p/506618

However, [this article from 538](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/spotify-knows-me-better-than-i-know-myself/) a journalist got a look at Nestify where that information is available.

I would assume that the information would eventually be made available via the API.